# Unable to upload rdl SSRS 2016

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Unable to upload rdls on SSRS 2016. Running on Windows Server 2012 R2.
Doesn't upload the report once the upload link is clicked.
Any suggestions?

Comment: When you click Upload link, it should open "Open  File" dialog - does it appear? What browser do you use?

Comment: Using IE. Yes it does open and I load an rdl. But that's it. It doesn't show up on SSRS. But if I create a new report it does show up.

Comment: Reports can be uploaded with Chrome. Are any Javascript errors being shown in the console?

Comment: Looks like it was an IE issue. Restoring settings solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was an IE issue. Restoring settings solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to:

1. Create new report using SSRS website and then try to replace it with you rdl file
2. Deploy report directly from Visual Studio
3. Check if report doesn't appear hidden (look for View->Show Hidden Items)
4. If you reports were created for older versions of SQL Server they might need to be upgraded ([more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143674.aspx))

I have noticed strange behaviour when upload data sources to SSRS 2016, did not have issues with RDLs but is worth to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, installing the **Chrome browser** (standalone) allowed us to use the upload functionality of the SSRS website.

Internet Explorer definitely have some issues, most likely security related.
We have not tested it with the Edge browser yet.

Also, the SSRS in question runs on Server 2016. Direct Visual Studio download is not an option due to tight VPN and firewall security.

RDL files developed with 2012 Data Tools uploaded without a problem. However, as suggested, it might be better to upgrade the project to 2016.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other options worked.  There is a new download button, that allows you to install a lightweight report builder.  You can then open your RDL and publish, etc. and obviously do the other lightweight things like check datasources, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and was not able to upload the RDL files as well as I was also not been able to create a data source (Something Went Wrong)on the SSRS 2017, the Web Service URL was also not working. finally, it worked by following the below steps:

Uninstall the SSRS
Install the SSRS Again
Configure the service account,
Web Service URL Use the Recommended setting and apply
Configure a new Database with an SSO account
Web portal URL Use the Recommended setting and apply

Try uploading the .rdl files and Create Datasource.

Note: if you have two separate servers for SQL and SSRS Please make sure the firewall is open for the webserver to connect the SQL server on ports 1433 and 80.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue and would get "Something went wrong" error when both uploading rdl files and changing data sources. Fixed it by going to uninstall SSRS from the server, and choosing "Repair". Rebooted, and issue fixed.